# How to write a reusable method in JAVA to count the number of classes(eg: <owl:Classes>...</owl:classes>) in ontology (.owl) file?

Tags: java

used for testing in Junit

```
assertEquals(olgaVisitor.getMapIRI_to_Zclass().entrySet()size(), 47);
```

want to get total number in place of 47 now it is hardcoded

Comment: Hi, check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure you will receive more attention.

Comment: Thanks in advance